# CSS bottom border is shorter when using pseudo :after

Tags: css, css-animations, pseudo-element

When my web page loads it plays this bottom border animation, then afterwords it will display a static bottom border. The issue is, you can see from this snippet that the animated border is shorter than the static border.. How can I center this so both borders are identical at the end result? I would ideally like both borders to look like the second, longer one shown in the snippet.

I have played around with the width but can't seem to figure out what parameter needs a change.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
       
<style>
    .border-bottom-animate:after {
         content: "";  
         display: block; 
         border-bottom: 5px dotted black; 
         width: 100%;
         animation-duration: 3s;
         animation-name: border-animation;
    }

    @keyframes border-animation {
      from {
         width: 0%;
      }
      to {
        width: 100%;
      }
   } 
   
   .border-bottom-noanimate {
       content: "";  
         display: block; 
         border-bottom: 5px dotted black; 
         width: 100%;
   }
</style>
    </head>
<body>

    <div class="container border-bottom-animate">
        <p style="font-size: xx-large">
           border animation
        </p>
        
    </div>
    
     <div class="container border-bottom-noanimate">
        <p style="font-size: xx-large">
           border no animation
        </p>
        
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can add a position:relative to the container, and set its after pseudo-element’s pasition to absolute and left to 0, so that it’ll start right from the beginning of its container.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
       
<style>
    .container{
         position:relative;
    }
    .border-bottom-animate:after {
         content: "";  
         position:absolute;
         left:0;
         display: block; 
         border-bottom: 5px dotted black; 
         width: 100%;
         animation-duration: 3s;
         animation-name: border-animation;
    }

    @keyframes border-animation {
      from {
         width: 0%;
      }
      to {
        width: 100%;
      }
   } 
   
   .border-bottom-noanimate {
       content: "";  
         display: block; 
         border-bottom: 5px dotted black; 
         width: 100%;
   }
</style>
    </head>
<body>

    <div class="container border-bottom-animate">
        <p style="font-size: xx-large">
           border animation
        </p>
        
    </div>
    
     <div class="container border-bottom-noanimate">
        <p style="font-size: xx-large">
           border no animation
        </p>
        
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok this is very close but the only issue is the border will now span the entire page instead of the width of the container it's applied to. Can't really tell in the snippet.

Comment: Never mind. Had to add position:relative to the container style. Brilliant answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `:after` pseudo-element is only as wide as the content inside the padding. You need to add the size of the padding to your `:after`'s width. Then adjust the margin to account for the greater width. Bootstrap uses `calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5)` to define the `padding-left` and `padding-right` of a `.container`.
See my comments in the snippet CSS below. I minimalized the snippet but, there are only 2 lines with a change plus 2 comment lines from your code.

```css
.border-bottom-animate:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 5px dotted black;
  /* add the bootstrap gutter width */
  width: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) + 100%);
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: border-animation;
  /* give a negative x margin half the gutter width */
  margin: 0 calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * -.5);
}

@keyframes border-animation {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) + 100%);
  }
}

.border-bottom-noanimate {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 5px dotted black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container border-bottom-animate">
  <p style="font-size: xx-large">
    border animation
  </p>

</div>

<div class="container border-bottom-noanimate">
  <p style="font-size: xx-large">
    border no animation
  </p>

</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```